# MYSQL Return string is not Displaying N/A when Null or Empty

Tags: mysql

So i renew mypost and here is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(DATE(date_opened)) as 'Total for this Date'
FROM daily_report
WHERE DATE(date_opened)>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY )
GROUP BY DATE(date_opened) DESC
```

and it's it working and here is the return query

```
**Total Number for this date**
|              3              |
|              1              |
|              2              |
```

But now When i add the `AND survey_at_what_blh='Tokyo'`  I'm getting an Empty String so added this command

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DATE(date_opened)) IS NULL
        THEN 'N/A'
        WHEN COUNT(DATE(date_opened)) = ''
        THEN 'N/A'
        ELSE COUNT(DATE(date_opened)) END  AS wut
FROM daily_report
WHERE DATE(date_opened)>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY ) AND survey_at_what_blh='Tokyo'
GROUP BY DATE(date_opened) DESC
```

And Now I'm still getting some empty string after running this command. But I also use this command in my other self-study project and it work but here its not working

Comment: You could improve this question by supplying sample date and expected output as text

Answer (score 0):

Create the days you are interested in using cte or sub query, left join to data and sum

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T(DT DATETIME);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
('2021-03-05 21:44:12'),        
('2021-03-03 08:46:33'),       
('2021-03-03 08:46:33'),
('2021-03-02 08:46:33');  

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT DATE(NOW()) DT
 UNION  SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
 UNION  SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()) ,INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
)
SELECT CTE.DT,SUM(CASE WHEN T.DT IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CNT
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN T ON DATE(T.DT) = CTE.DT
GROUP BY CTE.DT
ORDER BY CTE.DT;

+------------+------+
| DT         | CNT  |
+------------+------+
| 2021-03-03 |    2 |
| 2021-03-04 |    0 |
| 2021-03-05 |    1 |
+------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.019 sec)
```